# PHP Optimisation is this correct?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, query-optimization

I have been creating a php application that makes quite a few **queries** to the database i'd say roughly around 30 or so each page load. This is needed due to the nature of the application. I am using OOP php techniques and optimising my queries as much as I can. Should I be using some sort of caching system? or would you say 30 is fine? Here is a typical query.

Ok so my `__construct` looks like this:

```
public function __construct($host = 'localhost', $user = 'root', $pass = 'root', $name = 'advert') 
    {   
        $this->_conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name)
            or trigger_error('Unable to connect to the server, please check your credentials.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
```

And one method like so.

```
$sql = "SELECT `advert_id`,
                        `ad_title`,
                        `ad_image` FROM adverts WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() < `ad_expires` AND `ad_show` = 0 AND `ad_enabled` = 1 ORDER BY `ad_id` DESC LIMIT 1";

        $stmt = $this->_conn->prepare($sql);
        if ($stmt) {
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($ad_id, $ad_title, $ad_image);
            $rows = array();
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                $item = array(
                    'ad_id' => $ad_id,
                    'ad_title' => $ad_title,
                    'ad_image' => $ad_image
                );
                $rows[] = $item;
            }
```

The app is kinda like this throughout.

Thanks any feedback will be much appreciated.

**EDIT Sorry i meant to say 30 queries not 30 connections

Comment: Do not use a new connection for each object.  That's ridiculous.  Use a shared DB object.  Personally, I often store mine in `$GLOBALS` depending on the project, but there are other ways to do it.

Comment: 30 *queries* is fine, 30 *connections* is not. Unless you are connecting to 30 different databases.

Comment: Oh no, I upvoted Brad's comment before reading it to end. In `$GLOBAL`, really? It's much more ridiculous, than 30 connections per page.

Comment: If you're using $GlOBALS, you're doing it wrong.  Look into using dependency injection.

Comment: What kind of usage are you anticipating?  Thirty queries per page does sound like a lot, but on a departmental site, probably not an issue.  If you're expecting a million hits an hour, it's probably a lot.  And caching can help but it also going to be dependent on what you cache.  If everyone is seeking unique data in every query, it's not gonna help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make one connection and re-use it. 30 connections is a lot considering that you might have multiple users.

Edit: initial question said connections. 30 queries is fine unless this is data that doesn't change very often. In this case you can first do a query to see if you need to pull data or if the cached data is fine to serve to the user.

Comment: Sorry guys i meant to say 30 queries only 1 connection is made.

Answer (score 1):

You should use caching when it will useful. If time of page generation without caching of queries is 3 seconds, and with caching - 0.03, then you should use caching, obviously. If caching not gives any noticeable boost - don't spend resources.